# Update Google pay integration

Tags: android, flutter, react-native, stripe-payments, google-play

I have successfully set up android google pay integration on google pay business console and it has been approved, however now I have made changes to the user interface (the payment flow) how can I update the new screenshots on the google pay business console `( Item selection, Pre-purchase screen, Payment method screen, etc)`

The message that is said in the google pay business console is:

```
Your integration has been approved!
If you need to change something, you'll need to set up a new integration, have it approved and then delete the original integration.
```

But I don't see any way to update the integration or set up a new one.

Comment: Perhaps contact them, we are not their helpline.

Comment: I did already but I am hoping that someone already go through this and know what I should do